# Filebeat 7.10.1 add_docker_metadata adds only container.id

Tags: docker, filebeat

I'm using filebeat 7.10.1 installed on host system (not docker container), running as service by root

according to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/add-docker-metadata.html
and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-container.html

filebeat config, filebeat.yml:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'
  processors:
    - add_docker_metadata: ~

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false

setup.kibana:

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["<logstash_host>:5044"]
```

started container:
`docker run --rm -d -l my-label --label com.example.foo=bar -p 80:80 nginx`

filebeat get logs and successfully send them to endpoint (in my case to logstash, which resend to elasticsearch), **but generated json by filebeat contains only container.id without container.name, container.labels and container.image**

it looks like (copy-paste from kibana):

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2021.02.10",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "s4a4i3cB8j0XLXFVuyMm",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "ecs": {
      "version": "1.6.0"
    },
    "@timestamp": "2021-02-10T11:33:54.000Z",
    "host": {
      "name": "<some_host>"
    },
    "input": {
      "type": "container"
    },
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ],
    "log": {
      .....
    },
    "stream": "stdout",
    "container": {
      "id": "15facae2115ea57c9c99c13df815427669e21053791c7ddd4cd0c8caf1fbdf8c-json.log"
    },
    "agent": {
      "version": "7.10.1",
      "ephemeral_id": "adebf164-0b0d-450f-9a50-11138e519a27",
      "id": "0925282e-319e-49e0-952e-dc06ba2e0c43",
      "name": "<some_host>",
      "type": "filebeat",
      "hostname": "<some_host>"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "log.timestamp": [
      "2021-02-10T11:33:54.000Z"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-02-10T11:33:54.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "log.logger_name": [
      "@kibana-highlighted-field@gw_nginx@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1612956834000
  ]
}
```

what am I doing wrong? How to configure filebeat for send container.name, container.labels, container.image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking on filebeat-debug and paths on filesystem - issue closed

Reason: symlink /var/lib/docker -> /data/docker produces unexpected behavior

Solution:

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: container
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - '/data/docker/containers/*/*.log' #use realpath
    processors:
      - add_docker_metadata:
           match_source_index: 3 #subfolder for extract container id from path
```